# Unable to render alpha channel as a texture in WebGL

Tags: textures, webgl

I am reading a alpha channel of a DICOM file which has the image data , after that I am parsing and rendering it using [this tutorial](http://studyjs.com/html5/dicom.html) , in addition to that I am forwarding the alpha channel to a webgl program to render the texture.

However, it works for few images , it also fails for some.
Here are few use cases :

**SNO** **Width**  **Height** **Status**

1. Width : 628 , Height : 888, Length of alpha channel : 557664 (Works fine).
2. Width : 448 , Height : 612, Length of alpha channel : 274176(Works fine).
3. Width : 446 , Height : 612, Length of alpha channel : 272952(Doesn't work).
4. Width : 2219 , Height : 1200, Length of alpha channel : 2662800(Doesn't work).

And for Use case 3 and 4 I get these error messages :

- Error: WebGL: texImage2D: Provided buffer is too small. (needs 2663999, has 2662800)
- Error: WebGL: generateMipmap: The base level of the texture does not have power-of-two dimensions.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

The errors are actually what they say.

1. `Error: WebGL: texImage2D: Provided buffer is too small. (needs 2663999, has 2662800)`

   you called `gl.texImage2D` but the dimensions of the texture were larger than the data you provided.

   For example if you did this

   ```
   var width = 16;
   var height = 16;
   gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, width, height, 0,
                 gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, new Uint8Array(10));
   ```

   You'd get the same error. You specified a texture 16x16xRGBA(4) which
   means that data has to be 16*16*4 or 1024 bytes but the code above only passed 10 bytes

   One thing to be aware of is the `UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` setting. It defaults to 4
   which means each row of data will be padded to 4 bytes. In other words and alpha texture of 7x3 will be

   ```
   width = 7
   height = 3
   bytesPerPixel = 1   // gl.ALPHA
   unpaddedRowSize = width * bytesPerPixel
   paddedRowSize = Math.floor((minBytesPerRow + 3) / 4) * 4;  // = 8
   requiredDataSize = (height - 1 * paddedRowSize) + unpaddedRowSize
   ```

   You might have thought you only need 7x3 or 21 bytes for ALPHA but you actually need 8+8+7 or 23 bytes since each row except the last is padded to a multiple of 4

   You can tell WebGL to set the UNPACK_ALIGNMENT to 1 by calling

   ```
   gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
   ```

   Now it will only need 21 bytes as it will no longer pad the rows.
2. `Error: WebGL: generateMipmap: The base level of the texture does not have power-of-two dimensions`

   WebGL 1.0 can't use mips unless a texture is a power of 2 in both dimensions. None of your example textures are powers of 2 in either dimension so you can't use mips and you can't call `gl.generateMipmap` for them.

   Instead you must set your texture filtering to only use the top (0 level) mip

   ```
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR); // or gl.NEAREST
   ```

   and you must set wrapping to `CLAMP_TO_EDGE`

   ```
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
   ```

   WebGL 2.0 removes these restrictions

Comment: I tried all the suggestions provided by you but sadly nothing works, but if I save the alpha channel to a separate canvas and try to render that canvas as a texture in webgl , it works